# Javascript RegEx failing

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression that will ONLY accept files with JPEG, JPG or PDF format.  My attempt has been:

`/^image|\/(jpe?g|pdf)$/i`

But, as it stands, it won't accept PDF format (because of the 'image/*' portion).

Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: If you are only looking for a handful of allowable values, why use regex?

Comment: Just thought it would make this simpler. And I'm a bit anal retentive so I was wondering why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That expression doesn't make a lot of sense. You have an alternation there saying either match `^image` or match `/(jpe?g|pdf)$`.

If you want to match `image/jpg`, `image/jpeg`, and `application/pdf`, then:

```
/^(?:image\/jpe?g|application\/pdf)$/
```

Note, though, that PDFs can have a few other MIME types. Perhaps:

```
/^(?:image\/jpe?g|application\/(?:pdf|x-pdf|x-bzpdf|x-gzpdf))$/
```

...would be more inclusive.

Comment: `/^(?:image\/jpe?g)|(?:application\/pdf)$/` should probably be `/^(?:image\/jpe?g|application\/pdf)$/`

Comment: Wow, I really need to review RegEx...never paid much attention to them. Thank you. Works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Not everything needs to be a regular expression:

```
function isValidMimeType(type) {
    return [
        'image/jpg',
        'image/jpeg',
        'application/pdf',
        'application/x-pdf',
        'application/x-bzpdf',
        'application/x-gzpdf'
    ].indexOf(type) > -1;
}
```

If you *insist* on using regular expressions, I recommend using multiple so that the code is still readable:

```
function isValidMimeType(type) {
    if (/^image\/jpe?g$/.test(type)) {
        return true;
    } else if (/^application\/(?:x-|x-bz|x-gz)?pdf$/.test(type)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Of course, this code could be written shorter. There's no reason to though. You sacrifice readability when you condense it down to:

```
function isValidMimeType(type) {
    return /^(?:image\/jpe?g|application\/(?:x-(?:bz|gz)?)?pdf)$/.test(type);
}
```

Good luck ever adding another mime type to that.